# Textbox cannot be cleared with button press

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I keep getting an error message whenever I tried to clear textBox2. How can I solve this?

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HexKey = this.textBox2.Text;
        if(textBox2.Focused)
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(HexKey, 16);
    }

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
```

[Error]:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex'

[Solution]:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HexKey = this.textBox2.Text;
        if(textBox2.Focused) //add this line in
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(HexKey, 16);
    }
```

Comment: There is no way that this code reproduces your problem. There is no `startIndex` parameter to either of those function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firzanah,
When you clear textBox2, the TextChanged event will trigger. Since there won't be anything in your text box at that point, an error will occur when you try to convert nothing to an int32. To solve this problem, add an `if(textBox2.Focused)` condition to your change event or, better yet, just check that what you've got is an int to begin with:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out n);
            if (!isNumeric) return;
            string HexKey = textBox2.Text;
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(HexKey, 16);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Error will genereate because you convert nothing value to an int32 and
>   please try with this code

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n,key;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtBox2.Text, out n))
        return;
    else
       key = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox2.Text, 16);
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox2.Text="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that the clear event is triggering correctly and right after that your onChange event is triggering as well, sending an empty string to you code which is where the exception is coming from.

I suggest surrounding your code with Try...Catch blocks thay way the origin of the exception is clearer or as @cody gray suggested simply use the debugger.

Comment: Try/Catch blocks don't make the origin of an exception any clearer. If anything, they obfuscate it. A debugger will easily allow you to find the source of an exception.